# Passing value from popup window to parent form's TextBox

Tags: asp.net

Work on ASP.NET Visual Studio 2008 C#. I have a page. From this page I need to call a page on popup. On the popup page selected value will be set on the parent page text control.

> 1. One parent page
> 2. One child page.
> 3. Call parent to child as popup.
> 4. On popup window contain a grid.
> 5. On popup grid have command select,click on select  close popup and selected value will set on parent page text control.

I have done steps 1,2,3 and 4. But I need to complete step no 5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On parent page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function f1() {
        window.open("child.aspx");
    }
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><input type="button" onclick="f1();" value="pop up" />
```

On child page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function f2() {

    opener.document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "hello world";
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="return hello world" onclick="f2();" />
```

Also you can pass ID of control which you want fill from child page as GET parameter:

```
window.open("child.aspx?controlID=<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>");
```