# How can I refresh only a GridView in a parent window with JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have two aspx files for adding/deleting products to/from a sale.

1. islemler.aspx
2. SatisTedarik.aspx

I have a GridView in islemler.aspx, this gridView's name is `islemlerGridView` when a line is selected on `islemlerGridView` a button appears, and name of this button is `islemDetayGorButton`.

When `islemDetayGorButton` is clicked SatisTedarik.aspx is opened. On SatisTedarik.aspx there are many elements such as labels, textboxes, dropdownlists, gridviews and via this SatisTedarik.aspx window user can add/delete a product to/from sale(sales are shown in `islemlerGridView`).

What I need to do is, to update `islemlerGridView` when something about the sale is changed via SatisTedarik.aspx.

I found this question [Passing value from popup window to parent form's TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091772/passing-value-from-popup-window-to-parent-forms-textbox)
and tried something with JavaScript and I gotta say I do not have JavaScript experience.
I tried refreshing the opener window, and in my condition opener window is islemler.aspx I used the below code on SatisTedarik.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function f2() {
            opener.document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "hello world";//this is just from that example in the link

            opener.document.location.reload(true);//that is how I refresh islemler.aspx

        } 
</script>
```

And this is the button which uses `f2()`

```
<input type="button" value="return hello world" onclick="f2();" />
```

Yes this code refreshes islemler.aspx but the canges made via SatisTedarik.aspx is not reflected on `islemlerGridView`.

For example,

1. suppose `islemlerGridView` shows
   sale id and sale total money.
2. And let's say  I have Sale X in
   which Product A is sold and Product
   A costs 10 money.
3. I am choosing Sale X on
   `islemlerGridView` and
   `islemDetayGorButton` appears then I
   click this button and it opens
   SatisTedarik.aspx.
4. In SatisTedarik.aspx I am adding
   Product B which costs 5 money to
   Sale X and save it.

At last, I click the button which uses `f2()` and it refreshes islemler.aspx but Sale X's sale total money cell is still 10 money, however I need it to be 15 money as I added a new product on that sale.

So my *first question is what am i supposed to do to get expected result?*(**solved**)

*Question :* **Secondly, is there any way I can refresh only islemlerGridView but not the whole page?**

**Ok it turns out this is working for my first question**

```
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
```

so my first question has an answer now.

*Question :* **is there any way I can refresh only `islemlerGridView` but not the whole page?**

(I tried all those in IE9 and Mozilla Firefox 4)

Links I've checked and found something good:

1. [Javascript - Refresh Parent
   Window?](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=35326)
2. [refresh parent after closing pop up
   window](http://www.codetoad.com/forum/15_25443.asp)
3. [Refreshing parent window](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t69839-refreshing-parent-window.html)
4. [Refresh the parent window from the
   child window in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762329/refresh-the-parent-window-from-the-child-window-in-javascript)
5. [Refresh parent window from child
   window using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667714/refresh-parent-window-from-child-window-using-javascript)

Comment: Errrr could you *please* structure your question in such a way that we can actually see where the question is?

Comment: @Aron Well, there is a _Question_ word before my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created an UpdatePanel named `GridRefreshPanel` and I put the grid into that panel and used this

```
function f2() {
              window.opener.__doPostBack('GridRefreshPanel.ClientID', '');    
              //window.opener.__doPostBack('islemlerGridView.ClientID', ''); //this is also working without GridRefreshPanel 
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function ReloadParent()
{
    if (window.parent) 
    { 
          window.parent.location.replace(window.parent.location.href);
    }
}
```

this code will reload your parent page from your child page.....

Comment: yes thanks Dot Net Developer I handled that issue.However, I want to refresh **only** the GridView on my parent page **not the whole page** if possible, you have any idea about that?

Comment: I added this code on my child page, but this code is not reloading the parent page.

Comment: first check it calls or not on child page and if it gives you error then what error it throw?

Comment: Well Dot Net Developer thanks for the response it works when I use `window.opener` instead of `window.parent`.However, the Gridview on the parent page still does not show the updated information.