# Update gridview without refreshing the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Right now i m redirecting to same page for showing updated values in grid view. but i want to do that staying on the same page.I am using List as DataSource and not any Database.

Comment: Why don't you modify the DataSource of the GridView accordingly and call `grid.DataBind()`. Apart from that, show what you've tried.

Comment: @manthan9311 please do up vote correct answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
    </asp:GridView>
```

BY DOING enableviewstate=”false” we make sure we are seeing updated data.!

Comment: That is simply wrong. [TRULY Understanding ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx)

Comment: thanks. i was using collections so it was possible. but in case of database i should use updatepanel. thanks 4 correction. Tim.

Comment: How can we do paging when using gridview in updatepanel as it is not supported for details check following link : 
[Update Panel Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295545.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Try using an UpdatePanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdtPnlForGrdVw" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ...></asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

As we set UpdateMode to Conditional we mean that

> We will be updating the content of the `UpdtPnlForGrdVw` manually.

After binding data to the gridview use

```
UpdtPnlForGrdVw.Update()
```

to update the contents of the updatepanel which in your condition will be the gridview.

You can also do this with JavaScript, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/6177348/647884, remember  you won't need the opener in your case if you try the solution in the link.

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned that he wants to use ajax or that the flicker is the issue.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well Tim, you are right but it is still a solution isn't it? Plus I am just suggesting things he doesn't have to mention using ajax, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: This is not even a comment (although it   is a  step in the right direction).

Comment: But it can be helpful to someone else who will read this "comment" )